# Stored Prc and System Variable

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm currently monitoring the amount of prepared statements open within our MariaDB instance.
Using the command :

show status like 'prepared_stmt_count'

Which returns
Variable_name         Value
Prepared_stmt_count   27782

I would like to add this into a stored Proc which when executed outputs the value via a variable.

However If I try something as simple as

set p_out = show status like 'prepared_stmt_count'

Then I get a sql error. SP's are a pretty new thing to me, so I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information_schema;

```
select VARIABLE_VALUE INTO @v FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='prepared_stmt_count';
```

This does a user variable, however other stored procedure vars should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. prepapred_stmt_count returns the total number or prepared statements in use. Does your applications really need to keep 27782 statements in open state? If a statement will not be used it should be closed immediately to free resources.

2. It doesn't make sense to write a stored procedure for getting this value when you can use a simple select:

`SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="prepared_stmt_count"`

or if you want to store the value in a user variable

`SELECT @p_out:= VARIABLE_VALUE ..`